# Trying to create a hibernate query not sure if understanding correctly

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is a sample structure of what I am dealing with

```
class Item{
   Date date;
   MetaData metaData;
}

class MetaData{
   SysData sysData;
}

class SysData{
    Set<Category> categories;
    Set<Keyword> keywords;
}
```

On the UI the user should be able to view all Items in a table. They should be able to filter for Items with a certain date as well as any number of keywords or categories.

Lets say I create an Item with category "New" "Male" and keyword "Fast" "Pretty". If I want to display all Items with New category, I just select the New tag in a dropdown and click Query. How do I go about creating this type of query?

Here is what I have tried

....

```
Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(Item.class, "item");
criteria.createAlias("metaData", "meta");
criteria.createAlias("meta.sysData", "sys");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("sys.categories", myCategories);
```

I have tried some slight variations but am I headed in the right direction at least? Hopefully this is enough information. Does it even matter if the SysData is related to Item?

Comment: If Hibernate's Criteria API is anything like TopLink's (the RI bundled with Glassfish), you'll have an easier time using the query language, HQL. Have a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm and search the web for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(Item.class, "item");
criteria.createAlias("metaData", "meta");
criteria.createAlias("meta.sysData", "sys");
criteria.createAlias("sys.categories", "ctg");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("ctg", myCategories);
```